# Weekly auto email

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to send auto email report weekly every monday @10 am but the following code is not working.It gets triggered weekly after every 1 hour.Please help

Below is the code I have written.

```
def send_daily():

        '''Check reports to be sent daily'''

  current_day = calendar.day_name[now_datetime().weekday()]
        now = frappe.utils.now_datetime()

        current_time = now.strftime("%H")

        enabled_reports = frappe.get_all('Auto Email Report',

                filters={'enabled': 1, 'frequency': ('in', ('Daily', 'Weekdays', 'Weekly'))})

        for report in enabled_reports:

  auto_email_report = frappe.get_doc('Auto Email Report', report.name)

                # if not correct weekday, skip

if auto_email_report.frequency == "Weekdays":

  if current_day in ("Saturday", "Sunday"):

     continue

  elif auto_email_report.frequency == 'Weekly':

 if auto_email_report.day_of_week != current_day:

  if auto_email_report.schedule_time != current_time:

  continue
                elif auto_email_report.frequency == "Daily":

 if auto_email_report.schedule_time != current_time:

 continue


  auto_email_report.send()
```

I want the email to get triggered every monday weekly @10 am.

Comment: format code. Current version is useless. Downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you trigger by hour and not by day... try to check when the day time is changed not the hour.

Comment: Thank You @KmcASI i'll check

Comment: I think another solve will be to store some where the last time was send it and on every day on @10 am to see if has pass a week or month from last mail send it. sound complicated but in fact is very simple